# jQuery hide / show elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have 2 elements cols3 and cols4. If either one is hidden then by clicking a button that element is to be displayed.
But if both elements are hidden then by clicking a button only element col3 is to be displayed.

I tried with the following code :
but if both are hidden, by clicking the button both are displayed instead of only cols3.

Any help?

```
$('#plusexp').click(function() {
    if ($('.cols3:visible')) {
        if ($('.cols4:hidden')) {
            $('.cols4').show();
        }
    }
    if ($('.cols3:hidden')) {
        $('.cols3').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#plusexp').click(function() {
    if ($('.cols3').is(':hidden')) {
        $('.cols3').show();
    } else {
        if ($('.cols4').is(':hidden')) {
            $('.cols4').show();
        }
    }
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jN7bc/

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking **whether something exists**, **use `.length` property**. `.length` property contains number of elements matching the selector.

Watch [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SkxwQ/) to see that **without using `.length`**, you will always get `true` **regardless** of whether there is some element or not.

**EDIT:**

After rethinking this (your description, your code and what you really want to achieve) my opinion is that your code should look as follows (see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zVSpg/2/)):

```
$('#plusexp').click(function() {
    var $cols3 = $('.cols3');
    if ($cols3.is(':visible')){
        $('.cols4').show();
    };
    $cols3.show();
});
```

The reason for that is:

- you show `cols3` anyway, because:

  - if both `cols3` and `cols4` are visible, you show `cols3`,
  - if only one is shown, you show this element (if this is `cols3`, you show it, but if this is `cols4`, then showing `cols3` does not change anything),
- `cols4` is shown only when `cols3` is visible before clicking (if both are invisible, then only `cols3` is shown),
- it is better to cache elements (in this case there is only one variable: `$cols3`),

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$('#plusexp').click(function() {
    if ($('.cols4:hidden')) {
        $('.cols3').show();
    }
    else 
        $('.cols4').show();
    }        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect fix:

```
$('#plusexp').click(function() {
var f = $('.cols4').is(":hidden") ? "show" : "hide";
    if (f == 'hide' || f == 'Hide') {
       $('.cols3').show();
       $('.cols4').hide();
    }
    if (f == 'show' || f == 'Show') {
       $('.cols4').show();
       $('.cols3').hide();
    }
});
```

And [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/Cjhyt/).
This is an easy code to use an edit :D.